# resultset.isLast() is not working standalone application

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am using DB2 database with Java. I am required to find if the record in resultset is last record. For that, I am using the following code:

```
statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE , ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

and with resultset,

```
while(resultSet.next()){
        :
        :
    if(resultset.isLast()){
         //some code here
    }
        :
        :
}
```

Although resultset.isLast() works fine to return true on last record when the code is deployed on websphere application server, it does not work when same code in used in stand alone application. resultset.isLast() is always returning 'false' even if it reaches the last record in stand alone application.

Please let me know if something is wrong.

Thanks in advance.